# R doMC library detectCores misreporting number of cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, domc

An R instructor provided this code to ensure that students only use half the cores on their PCs/Laptops in parallel processing.  However, as shown below, the system report from my mac says I have 4 while this library seems to detect 8.  To make sure at least 1 or 2 cores are free, is this code set correctly?  Or should I alter the last line maybe with an `ifelse()` statement that tells it what to do when system specs don't agree with its detection?

R code:

```
# Setting Parallel processing
library(doMC)
library(parallel)
number_of_cores <- detectCores()
registerDoMC(cores = number_of_cores/2)
```

Output (how many cores it sees):

```
[1] 8
```

What "About this Mac" -> "System Report" reports for specs including cores:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,3
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP143.0160.B02
```

Comment: The issue here is number of threads versus number of cores. Cores are physical, while threads (more or less) split a core and are software driven. Do an online search for "threads versus cores" and you will find tons of material.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading

Comment: Try `detectCores(logical = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is number of threads versus number of cores. Cores are physical, while threads (more or less) split a core and are software driven.  This combination of arguments should get you just the cores:

```
detectCores(all.tests = FALSE, logical = FALSE)
```